# Error, se genera un registro vació en la base de datos con solo cargar la pagina

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7, registro

Hola soy estudiante universitario de Adm. mención Informática, en programación nos toca hacer un sitio web con PHP conectado a una base MySQL. Tengo el sitio listo en un 90% para lo pedido por el profesor.

Me quedé trabado en un problema, la pagina de productos con solo abrirla me hace un registro en la tabla Presupuesto, en esta pagina cada producto tiene su propio formulario para que desde allí mismo lo puedas agregar al presupuesto (carrito). La informacion de los productos me la jalo de la table "Productos" y todos los formularios para insertar un nuevo registro en la tabla "Presupuesto" funcionan, solo que no entiendo porque se hace un registro vacio automático cuando cargo la pagina (ojo solo sucede una vez ya que la llave no permite repetir registros iguales).

Nota: solo estoy usando PHP, HTML y CSS
https://mega.nz/file/XYpwnAqC#oKufMqExmEaq6uwxTULNA3fUhViY-hn9hZnK4w7NIbg

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cajita col-3">
                        <form action="page1.php" method="POST">
                            <div>
                                <img class="pre" src="assets/images/html.png">
                                <div class="cajaFlotante">
                                    <label id="agregarPresupuesto"><h5>Agregar al Presupuesto</h5></label>
                                <?php
                                    while ($colum1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                                        {
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_c_p_html" id="codigo_producto" class="form-control" value="'. $colum1['codigo_producto'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_p_html" id="precio" class="form-control" value="'. $colum1['precio'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="i_c_html" id="cantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad" required/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="previa" value="Agregar">   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </br>
                            <h3 class="tituloproducto">Curso HTML</h3>
                            <p class="descripcionproducto" align="justify">
                            <?php
                                echo $colum1['descripcion'];
                                }
                            ?>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cajita col-3">
                        <form action="page1.php" method="POST">
                            <div>
                                <img class="pre" src="assets/images/css.png">
                                <div class="cajaFlotante">
                                    <label id="agregarPresupuesto"><h5>Agregar al Presupuesto</h5></label>
                                <?php
                                    while ($colum2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                                        {
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_c_p_css" id="codigo_producto" class="form-control" value="'. $colum2['codigo_producto'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_p_css" id="precio" class="form-control" value="'. $colum2['precio'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="i_c_css" id="cantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad" required/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="previa" value="Agregar">   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </br>
                            <h3 class="tituloproducto">Curso CSS</h3>
                            <p class="descripcionproducto" align="justify">
                            <?php
                                echo $colum2['descripcion'];
                                }
                            ?>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cajita col-3">
                        <form action="page1.php" method="POST">
                            <div>
                                <img class="pre" src="assets/images/JavaScript.png">
                                <div class="cajaFlotante">
                                    <label id="agregarPresupuesto"><h5>Agregar al Presupuesto</h5></label>
                                <?php
                                    while ($colum3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
                                        {
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_c_p_js" id="codigo_producto" class="form-control" value="'. $colum3['codigo_producto'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_p_js" id="precio" class="form-control" value="'. $colum3['precio'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="i_c_js" id="cantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad" required/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="previa" value="Agregar">   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </br>
                            <h3 class="tituloproducto">Curso JavaScript</h3>
                            <p class="descripcionproducto" align="justify">
                            <?php
                                echo $colum3['descripcion'];
                                }
                            ?>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cajita col-3">
                        <form action="page1.php" method="POST">
                            <div>
                                <img class="pre" src="assets/images/bootstrap.png">
                                <div class="cajaFlotante">
                                    <label id="agregarPresupuesto"><h5>Agregar al Presupuesto</h5></label>
                                <?php
                                    while ($colum4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4))
                                        {
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_c_p_bootstrap" id="codigo_producto" class="form-control" value="'. $colum4['codigo_producto'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_p_bootstrap" id="precio" class="form-control" value="'. $colum4['precio'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="i_c_bootstrap" id="cantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad" required/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="previa" value="Agregar">   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </br>
                            <h3 class="tituloproducto">Curso Bootstrap</h3>
                            <p class="descripcionproducto" align="justify">
                            <?php
                                echo $colum4['descripcion'];
                                }
                            ?>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cajita col-3">
                        <form action="page1.php" method="POST">
                            <div>
                                <img class="pre" src="assets/images/php.png">
                                <div class="cajaFlotante">
                                    <label id="agregarPresupuesto"><h5>Agregar al Presupuesto</h5></label>
                                <?php
                                    while ($colum5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
                                        {
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_c_p_php" id="codigo_producto" class="form-control" value="'. $colum5['codigo_producto'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_p_php" id="precio" class="form-control" value="'. $colum5['precio'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="i_c_php" id="cantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad" required/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="previa" value="Agregar">   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </br>
                            <h3 class="tituloproducto">Curso PHP</h3>
                            <p class="descripcionproducto" align="justify">
                            <?php
                                echo $colum5['descripcion'];
                                }
                            ?>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cajita col-3">
                        <form action="page1.php" method="POST">
                            <div>
                                <img class="pre" src="assets/images/MySQL.png">
                                <div class="cajaFlotante">
                                    <label id="agregarPresupuesto"><h5>Agregar al Presupuesto</h5></label>
                                <?php
                                    while ($colum6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result6))
                                        {
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_c_p_mysql" id="codigo_producto" class="form-control" value="'. $colum6['codigo_producto'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                        echo '<input type="text" name="i_p_mysql" id="precio" class="form-control" value="'. $colum6['precio'] . '" readonly required/>';
                                ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="i_c_mysql" id="cantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="cantidad" required/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="previa" value="Agregar">   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </br>
                            <h3 class="tituloproducto">Curso MySQL</h3>
                            <p class="descripcionproducto" align="justify">
                            <?php
                                echo $colum6['descripcion'];
                                }
                            ?>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>            
</section>
```

Comment: y el codigo php? de la page1.php?

Comment: Lo subí haca, me parece que es mas fácil https://mega.nz/file/XYpwnAqC#oKufMqExmEaq6uwxTULNA3fUhViY-hn9hZnK4w7NIbg

Comment: ya vi cual es el error, cuando cargas un .php con HTML primero realiza el proceso php y despues el HTML por lo cual estas insertando en el header, si quieres insertar con el mismo php, tienes que poner una condicional para ver si esta recibiendo datos del formulario html

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo para eliminar el registro automático que se generaba al abrir la pagina, el detalle es que sigue generando ese registro de más cuando presiono el input del formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que suelo hacer cuando proceso el form en el mismo archivo php es poner un `if` antes de mostrar el form. Yo le pongo la propiedad `name` al submit, en tu caso:

```
<input type="submit" class="previa" name="agregar" value="Agregar">
```

Y verifico con:

```
if (isset($_POST) and isset($_POST['agregar']) and ($_POST['agregar'] == "Agregar")) { *tu código*; }
```

Si el `form` me lleva a otro archivo, meto el `if` en ese archivo, en tu caso, `page1.php`.

No sé si es la única o la mejor o la mas óptima forma.